# Text editor that can be used inside an application

Tags: android, text-editor

How can i integrate a text editor in my app?
I need a text editor like Stack Exchange's one, which allows the user to post questions along with code snippets.

Comment: Use an EditText-inherited custom control.

Comment: edit text is a default view in android and i need to use a rich text editor which can provide me options like formatting my code/content, or highlighting the code. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sure. That's why you must create a customized version of that one, with syntax highlighting and so on. It won't be an easy task.

Comment: Are there any pre defined libraries which can be imported in my project to make my work easier.

Comment: Try googling. I'm sure there are a lot of ready-made rich text editor controls.

Comment: i didn't find any. That's why i posted here for the best solutions irrespective of the down votes i am getting for asking a question never seen before on this platform.

Comment: There are 2 options: **1** - You don't know how to google. **2** - You didn't search at all. By googling for `android rich text editor` I found a billion of results. This is why your question is getting downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create custom editext ( with for example snippets ) You need to create class extending edittext:

```
class CustomEditText extends EditText{

... class code
}
```

next use it in layout

```
<example.app.customedittext>
</example.app.customedittext>
```

This is ofcourse only beggining, so to create some complex widget i would create class like - **PostEditor** and inside it create some layout with buttons like bold,italic next create extended **EditText** like I showed above with own events. This is big case but now You should know how to start.